# Zero Probability Events

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

*For an uncountable number of zero-probability events, their union may not be zero-
probability.*

Is there an example of such a case?
I was told that this is why we cannot have uncountable additivity in the probability axioms.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. All singletons $\{x\}$ have probability $0$, but their (uncountable) union is the whole interval $[0,1]$ which has probability $1$.

Really, this example with singletons applies to any continuous distribution.

If you want more exotic events, you can pick the set $\mathbb{Z}$ of integers or set $\mathbb{Q}$ of rationals and all their cosets under addition - there are uncountably many cosets, each with measure $0$ (with respect to a continuous distribution), and their union is the whole real line, which has measure $1$.

Comment: Some would say the whole real line has measure $\infty$, not $1$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Indeed, most of the time we talk about measures of sets of reals we are referring to the Lebesgue measure (though of course here we are discussing a probability measure).